# SQL Server OpenQuery Invalid Syntax in EXEC Only

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g

When I run this code I get no errors:

```
SELECT * INTO GT_Item 
FROM OPENQUERY(PLPPROD_LS, 
        'SELECT 
             ITEM_CODE AS GT_ITEM_CODE, ITEMC_CODE, ITEM_DESC, 
             VALID_CODE_PROD,
             CASE 
                WHEN ITEMC_CODE LIKE ''WIP%'' 
                  THEN ''WIP-''||(SELECT MAX(JOBOP.JOB_NO)||''-''||MAX(OPCLASS_CODE) FROM REC INNER JOIN JOBOP ON JOBOP.JOBOP_ID = REC.JOBOP_ID WHERE REC.ITEM_CODE = ITEM.ITEM_CODE)
                  ELSE ITEM_CODE 
             END AS GALAXY_ITEM_CODE
         FROM ITEM')
```

However, when I set `@sql NVARCHAR(2000)` equal to the string in the `openquery` and try to run

`DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT 
                 ITEM_CODE AS GT_ITEM_CODE, ITEMC_CODE, ITEM_DESC, 
                 VALID_CODE_PROD,
                 CASE 
                    WHEN ITEMC_CODE LIKE ''WIP%'' 
                      THEN ''WIP-''||(SELECT MAX(JOBOP.JOB_NO)||''-''||MAX(OPCLASS_CODE) FROM REC INNER JOIN JOBOP ON JOBOP.JOBOP_ID = REC.JOBOP_ID WHERE REC.ITEM_CODE = ITEM.ITEM_CODE)
                      ELSE ITEM_CODE 
                 END AS GALAXY_ITEM_CODE
             FROM ITEM'
EXEC('SELECT * INTO GT_Item FROM OPENQUERY(PLPPROD_LS, ''' + @SQL + ''')' )`

I get an invalid syntax error pointing to the `''WIP%''` section of the string. Further, if I change that condition to another one (e.g. `ITEMC_CODE IN ('WIP_PRT','WIP_LAM')`), I get the same error at the same section.

Why am I getting the error when I run the code one way and not the other? My other queries in the same stored procedure are executed the second way without issue.

The linked server is an oracle 11 server. I have not simplified the query, since the error message indicates that it is a syntax error.

EDIT:

To be clear:
`EXEC('SELECT * INTO GT_Item FROM OPENQUERY(PLPPROD_LS, ''' + @SQL + ''')' )` works when `@SQL` is set to many other things, including but not limited to `SELECT ITEM_CODE AS GT_ITEM_CODE, ITEMC_CODE, ITEM_DESC, VALID_CODE_PROD FROM ITEM`.  However, the listed String above with the `CASE` statement will only execute if I do not use `EXEC`, but rather write it in as shown.

EDIT2: Found solution, need to double escape the `'` in the @SQL string.  Don't know why that is, but replacing `''` with `''''` let EXEC run, and did not leave extra `'` in my final table.

Comment: But It's not a syntax error by itself.. If I have`@SQL = SELECT * FROM ITEM` it runs fine...

Comment: No it doesn't, going to try the second part of the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way do not rely on concatenation and multiple `''` and use parameters instead:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * INTO GT_Item FROM OPENQUERY(PLPPROD_LS, ''@SQL'')',
        @param_list NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)';

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
        @query,
        @param_list,
        @SQL;
```

**EDIT:**

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ''WIP-''||ITEM_CODE AS TEST FROM ITEM'

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * INTO GT_Item FROM OPENQUERY(PLPPROD_LS, ''' + @SQL + ''')'
SELECT @query

Result: 
SELECT * INTO GT_Item FROM OPENQUERY(PLPPROD_LS, 'SELECT 'WIP-'||ITEM_CODE AS TEST FROM ITEM')
```

Result is incorrect because it has missing  `''` near *WIP*

Correct query:

```
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ''''WIP-''''||ITEM_CODE AS TEST FROM ITEM'
```

Comment: Neither solution works.  The first has the same syntax error, the second has the syntax error at @SQL.  Clarified question above

Comment: @AdamMartin Edit your question and add `DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ....`, I need to see exact string. Add don't write it doesn't work but also share error message.

Comment: Added my SQL declaration... The syntax error just says 'syntax error near ____'

Comment: @AdamMartin It seams to me it doesn't like `||` operator. Try if this work `DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ITEM_DESC || ITEM_DESC FROM ITEM'`

Comment: @AdamMartin I guess using EXEC there is some syntax validation and it cannot understand what `||` means. At that phase it doesn't know it will be executed on remote site.

Comment: I thought that was a good guess, but nope, that runs fine... However, `'SELECT ''WIP-''||ITEM_CODE AS TEST FROM ITEM'` causes the error

Comment: @AdamMartin I think I got it. Wait for update my answer.

Comment: @AdamMartin As you mentioned it is incorrectly quoted. See syntax highlighting.